# XML schema

Tags: c#, python, ruby

I've a schema file (.xsd), I'd like to generate a xml document using this schema. Is there any online tool available,if not what is quickest way (like couple of lines of code using vb.net).

Thanks for your help.

-Vuppala

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correct, this tool might help.

[XML Generator](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xml_generator.html)

It's what I usually use when working with XML.

If you want a solution through code you can use this:

```
XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("po.xml", null);
textWriter.Formatting    = Formatting.Indented;
XmlQualifiedName qname   = new XmlQualifiedName("PurchaseOrder",       
                           "http://tempuri.org");
XmlSampleGenerator generator = new XmlSampleGenerator("po.xsd", qname);
genr.WriteXml(textWriter);
```

Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Download [pyXSD](http://pyxsd.org/).

Use it to build Python class definitions from the XSD's.

Build objects from those class definitions.

Save the Python objects in XML notation.

An alternative is [GenerateDS](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/generateDS.html).